# Is content length necessary on inline?

Tags: php, apache, yii, http-headers

I am asking this because my requests keep getting "Content Length Mismatch" on files larger than 4Mb even though the content length and the file size is exact match. If I remove the Content Length header, everything works fine.

Is there an advantage or necessity of using Content Length in the headers for inline content (not attachment)?

[EDIT] Code:

```
public function actionViewFile($id) {
    $model = File::model()->findByPk($id);
    if(!$model) {
        throw new CHttpException(404, "File not found");   
    }
    $data = file_get_contents($this->storageDir.'/'.$model->fileName);
    header('Content-type: '.$model->mime_type);
    header('Content-length: '.$model->size); //I have tried calling `mb_strlen($data);`
    echo $data;
    Yii::app()->end(); //I have tried calling `die;`
}
```

The framework I am using is Yii, which doesn't really matter for the context of this problem.

Comment: Are you using an IIS webserver? If so maybe http://forums.iis.net/t/1174461.aspx?Content+length+mismatch would be of some incite?

Comment: As many other HTTP headers, it's optional and provided as a convenience for the user (for instance, it allows the browser to display a "remaining time" indicator). But it's almost impossible to calculate if you use, e.g., transparent compression. Is that the case?

Answer (score 0):

The Content-Length entity-header field indicates the size of the entity-body, in decimal number of OCTETs, sent to the recipient or, in the case of the HEAD method, the size of the entity-body that would have been sent had the request been a GET.

Try using filesize() as per the following:

```
public function actionViewFile($id) {

    $model = File::model()->findByPk($id);

    if(!$model) {
        throw new CHttpException(404, "File not found");   
    }

    $filepath= $this->storageDir.'/'.$model->fileName;
    $data = file_get_contents($filepath);

    header('Content-type: '.$model->mime_type);
    header("Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate");
    header('Content-Length: ' . sprintf('%u', filesize($filepath)))

    echo $data;

    return Yii::app()->end(); //I have tried calling `die;`

}
```